# Why does cassandra cqlsh responds : Trigger class 'mypackage.myclass' couldn't be loaded

Tags: cassandra, triggers, openshift, cqlsh

I have created a trigger class 'mypackage.myclass' that works fine on standard cassandra container.
I have packaged everything under a single jar file in /etc/cassandra/triggers/my-fat-jar.jar
(permissions are root 644)

However, when I deploy that same container under Red Hat OpenShift CP, that trigger cannot be loaded. It is simply saying:

```
‘<stdin>:1:InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Trigger class 'mypackage.myclass' couldn't be loaded"’
```

I have no clue where that error could come from..
Would you have any idea where to look at ?

Thank you.

Versions used:
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.1 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be certain without seeing how you are building the image and the file permissions in more detail, but since it appears that it might be a file permissions issue you might be running into a problem with Openshift security policies regarding arbitrary user ids. In theory the 644 permission should mean that this isn't a problem, but perhaps the arbitrary user is having trouble accessing the directory itself.

(Also, depending on what you have in your Dockerfile, you could try adding the `anyuid` SCC just to verify if this is the cause of your issue.)

In general, I'd walk through the [OpenShift platform-specific guidelines](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/openshift_images/create-images.html#images-create-guide-openshift_create-images) because that will give you specific instructions on making sure your file permissions will work.

I'd also just use `oc debug` to get a shell in the problematic container and just verify access to the relevant directories/files.

Comment: Thanks for reply David.
However, it does not seem to be a file permission issue.
```
$ id
uid=1001190000(1001190000) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1001190000
$ pwd
/etc/cassandra/triggers
$ ls -lrt
total 62504
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 cassandra cassandra       61 Aug 30 11:19 README.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root      root      63998959 Jan 26 18:08 cassandra-listener-1.0.0-PI4-SP2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```